# Azure Timer Function shows duplicated invocation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure timer function that kicks off every 5 minutes. It is hooked up to Application Insights and the invocation log shows it triggered twice for each time and the same operation ID.

Why the apparently spurious duplication of the invocation in the log?

The relevant code:

```
 public async Task RunEST([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *"
#if DEBUG
            , RunOnStartup = true
#endif
            )]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {...
```

Screenshot of the invocations in Azure:

[image: Screenshot of the invocations in Azure]

Comment: Code - https://i.imgur.com/3DhBiFM.png, Result - https://i.imgur.com/v72AdFB.png --> I didn't find any invocation Id twice. Could you please tell the steps how you run the function and verify the code screenshot I shared is similar to your code.

Comment: How did you integrate application insights?

Comment: @HariKrishna The function is run on a schedule to run  every 5 minutes.  The date/time in the screen shot shows it (apparently - to my untrained eyes) ran twice for each 5 minute interval.  Also, yes, the code look similar.

Comment: @PeterBons This might be relevant.  The function app was not hooked up to any ApplicaitonInsights. As a test, I hooked it up to one in a different resource group. when things seemed to be working, I created a new one and hooked it up there after unhooking from the test one.  This was several months ago so details and steps I took are fuzzy. Plus I'm a bit of a newbie on this.

Comment: @MarkG, Any update on the issue, did you tried deploying the same function to another function app and checked the invocation logs?

Comment: More details.
I've determined that the function isn't actually running more than once each interval. I call something externally and see it hit only one time.  
  
I'm the only one on our team that can see the logs inside application insights for this function
Inside each of the invocations, when i open it up to see each log entry, I see the log entries twice with the exact same timestamp.